# how to change the contents of the cell name when saving data excel to the database on laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

data excel like image below:

[image]

i want to change value when upload data from Excel to MySQL

if the cell has the name 'UNSIL' then when stored in the database will change to number '1'

i have code for uploading data from Excel to MySQL on laravel

```
public function importExcel(Request $request) {
        if($request->hasFile('import_file')) {
            $path = $request->file('import_file')->getRealPath();
            $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {})->get();
            if(!empty($data) && $data->count()) {
                foreach($data as $key => $value) {
                    $insert[] = ['nama_fakultas'=>$value->nama_fakultas,
                                 'nama_universitas'=>$value->nama_universitas,
                                 'keterangan'=>$value->keterangan
                                ];
                                if($value->nama_universitas = 'UNSIL') {
                                    $value->nama_universitas = '1';
                                }
                }
                if(!empty($insert)) {
                    DB::table('fakultas')->truncate($insert);
                    DB::table('fakultas')->insert($insert);

                    return redirect('fakultas');
                }

            }
        }
        return back();
    }
```

in the code above contains the data upload command from excel to mysql, and when I want to change the value of the name 'UNSIL' to number 1 nothing happens

can anyone help me for solve this case?

Comment: Check the order of your operations. First you're assigning the value to the `insert[]` array and then you change the value of `$value->nama_universitas`. Just switch that order.